# Symfony2, autoload service in service

Tags: symfony, service, autoloader

Question is simple but...
So we have main service:

```
class ManagerOne {}
```

and have several another services we want to use in main service:

```
class ServiceOne{}
class ServiceTwo{}
class ServiceThree{}
class ServiceFour{}
...
```

Each named as (in services.yml)

```
service.one
service.two
service.three
service.four
...
```

Locations of services is different, not in one folder (but I don't think it's a huge trouble for custom autoloader).

Regarding manual we can inject them via __construct() in main service (ManagerOne) but what if we got 20 such services need to be injected? Or use only that we need. Describe them in services as simple inject? O.o I think it's not good idea so.... Also we can inject container and that's it. BUT! Everywhere people saying that inject container worst solution.

What I want. I need method for ManagerOne service which will load service i need by 'service.name' or 'path' with checker 'service exist'.

Comment: If you need to connect the 20 services, it is a sign of bad architecture.

Comment: For example i have one item. That has 20 custom updaters. And i cannot combine them and make one factoryClass. Point is that I (in ManagerOne) check item, get its access to updaters, and only then start to load services it need. And after that through ManagerOne i can call updaters methods... A the end we have 'standalone' updaters (i need this) and manager class that can user them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [service tagging](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/components/dependency_injection/tags.html) and tag each service you want to use in your `ManagerOne` class. And either use constructor dependency injection or method injection.

Example:

First of all you need a compiler pass to collect your tagged services:

```
namespace ...\DependencyInjection\Compiler;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Reference;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class ExamplePass implements CompilerPassInterface
{

    public function process(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        if (!$container->hasDefinition("manager.one")) {
            return;
        }
        $services = array();
        foreach ($container->findTaggedServiceIds('managed_service') as $serviceId => $tag) {
            $alias = isset($tag[0]['alias'])
                ? $tag[0]['alias']
                : $serviceId;

            // Flip, because we want tag aliases (= type identifiers) as keys
            $services[$alias] = new Reference($serviceId);
        }
        $container->getDefinition('manager.one')->replaceArgument(0, $services);
    }
}
```

Then you need to add the compiler pass to your bundle class:

```
namespace Example\ExampleBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use ...\DependencyInjection\Compiler\ExamplePass;

class ExampleBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);
        $container->addCompilerPass(new ExamplePass());
    }
}
```

Now you can use your services:

```
# services.yml
manager.one:
    class: ManagerClass
    arguments:
        - [] # will be replaced by our compiler pass

services.one:
    class: ServiceOne
    tags:
        - { name: managed_service, alias: service_one }

services.two:
    class: ServiceTwo
    tags:
        - { name: managed_service, alias: service_two }
```

But caution if you get your manager, all service classes will be automatically created. If this is a performance drawback for you could pass only the service ids (not the Reference) to your management class. Add the `@service_container` as second argument and create the service as needed.

Comment: Can you show simple example, in manual (as always) there are a lot of rubish in examples... :(

Comment: +1. Never did it, but if I never need it, I suppose I'll do that way

Comment: thnx, I asked about real example because in manuals usual thing to show 'single point' of some part of code and never ready code\template. As some people saw link you gave if you will try it it won't work because in first part uses ***_chain name (of service) and in next without it that's why some manuals are really unuseful

Answer (score 0):

**Since 2017, Symfony 3.3** and [Symplify\PackageBuilder](https://github.com/Symplify/PackageBuilder#in-symfony) this gets even easier.

Thanks to this package, you can:

- **drop tags**
- have simple 5 line `CompilerPass` using strict types over strings

Let's get to your example

**Suppose you have**

- 1 manager - `UpdateManager` class
- many updaters - a class that implements `UpdaterInterface`

#### 1. Service Config using [PSR-4 autodiscovery](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/05/07/how-to-refactor-to-new-dependency-injection-features-in-symfony-3-3/#4-use-psr-4-based-service-autodiscovery-and-registration)

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true

    App\:
        resource: ../../src/App
```

#### 2. Collecting Compiler Pass

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Compiler\CompilerPassInterface;
use Symplify\PackageBuilder\Adapter\Symfony\DependencyInjection\DefinitionCollector;

final class CollectorCompilerPass implements CompilerPassInterface
{
    public function process(ContainerBuilder $containerBuilder)
    {
        DefinitionCollector::loadCollectorWithType(
            $containerBuilder,
            UpdateManager::class,
            UpdaterInterface::class,
            'addUpdater'
        );
    }
}
```

It collect all services of `UpdaterInterface` type 
and adds them via `addUpdater()` method to `UpdateManager`.

#### 3. Register Compiler Pass in Bundle

```
namespace App;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

final class UpdaterBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $container->addCompilerPass(new CollectorCompilerPass);
    }
}
```

And that's all!

#### How to add new updater?

Just create class, that implements `UpdaterInterface` and it will be loaded to `UpdateManager`.

- no tagging
- no manual service registration
- no boring work

Enjoy!